# When calling the webpack CLI, is there a way to know if the build has been successful or failed?

Tags: node.js, bash, webpack, build, webpack-cli

I have a `deploy.sh` file that will call `webpack` like:

```
webpack --config webpack.prod.js
```

Does that call return something that I can use to **know if the build has been successful or not?** Because I'd like to know if my `deploy.sh` script should continue or not.

Any other solutions to this?

Comment: *Does that call return something[?]* It does return an exit status (accessible through `$?`), have you tried checking it?

Comment: It does return a `string` with a bunch of info. I'll try to work with that. But you must be careful because this call with the error on the command itself does not return anything. For example: `webpack --config INEXISTENT_FILE.config.js`. But there is a string that returns after the build itself that I'll try to use to check for success or fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `exit code` from the webpack CLI script to detect this:

https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli#exit-codes-and-their-meanings

**build.sh**

```
webpack --config webpack.prod.js

EXIT_CODE=$?

if [[ EXIT_CODE == "0" ]]; then
  echo "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
  exit
else
  echo "ERROR ON BUILD SCRIPT"
  exit
fi
```